# Able to include file in ASP.NET, but not check if it exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, include, file-exists

I want to include certain files in my page.
I'm not always sure if they exists, so I have to check if they do. (Otherwise the page crashes, as you probably know)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %> 

<html>
<body>
<% bool exists;
   exists = System.IO.File.Exists("/extra/file/test.txt");
%> 

Test include:<br>
<!--#include file="/extra/file/test.txt"-->

</body>
</html>

</html>
```

While the include works, the code checking if the file exists does not.

If I remove this code:

```
<% bool exists;
   exists = System.IO.File.Exists("/extra/file/test.txt");
%>
```

Everything runs fine. 
I also tried putting it in a `<script runat="server">`  block, but it still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side includes (SSI) are executed before your code, so you can't do this way.

If your included file is just static information (i.e. without server-side code), you can do something like:

```
string file = Server.MapPath("~/extra/file/test.txt");
if(System.IO.File.Exists(file))
{
    Response.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
exists = System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/extra/file/test.txt"));
```

Comment: The Server.MapPath did it, indeed. The tilde did add a few maps to the structure, so I had to remove it, but still: success.

Answer (score 2):

Server-side includes are legacy ASP code and cannot be conditional. However, since you are using C# ASP.NET code, you can just read the file and output it using C# instead of the server-side include.

Here, if you get an error with your code, it is probably because something else is not configured properly for you to use it (security settings, maybe?).